Is it possible to pass a class or object as a parameter in a function?
In Python, we can set functions to take certain types as parameters (for e.g. calc_cost(rate:float)). I was wondering if I could do the same by specifying a class of object.
I'm working on a game where I have defined a function which takes several objects. I want to specify the type of object (a class it will take as a parameter. But whenever I have tried to implement classes in a function it never works.
Here's a small dummy program:
class Store:
    def calc_cost(rate: float, qty: int) -> float:
        return rate * qty
    
def sum_stores(store1, total):
    total += store1.calc_cost(15, 30)

total = 0

ice_cream_shop = Store()
sum_stores(ice_cream_shop, total)

The answer should be a number, but I am getting this:
TypeError: sum_stores() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
I have only given 2 arguments but Python detects 3. This only happens when I add an instance of a class. What is the problem, and how can I solve it? And if this has nothing to do with classes as parameters, how can I implement them if possible?

@SimonMᶜKenzie This was an accident, as I was playing around with the program before I copied the code here. Negligence on my part, but I assure you the program returns the same error.

You didn't define the instance method correctly. It will be given an implicit argument of type Store, but you must explicitly define the function to accept it, even if you don't use or need it.
class Store:
    def calc_cost(self, rate: float, qty: int) -> float:
        return rate * qty
    

You can't update an int argument in place; instead, return the value of store1.calc_cost to be added to a variable in the calling scope.
def sum_stores(store1):
    return store1.calc_cost(15, 30)

total = 0

ice_cream_shop = Store()
total += sum_stores(ice_cream_shop)


It might make more sense for each store to maintain its own total (which would give calc_cost, or a suitable renamed version of it, a reason to be an instance method). For example,
class Store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

    def update_total(self, rate: float, qty: int):
        self.total += rate * qty


ice_cream_shop = Store()
ice_cream_shop.update_total(15, 30)
assert ice_cream_shop.total == 450


Thank you for the clarifcation. I was not aware that the self argument was necessary for every method.

Because of how the descriptor protocol is implemented by the function type, ice_cream_shop.update_total(...) is effectively the same as Store.update_total(ice_cream_shop, ...), regardless of how the function is defined.

You should add a proper initialization method to your class; however, in the function 'calc_cost' in the class 'Store', you should add 'self' into the function as that's more appropriate for classes.
Also, your total variable won't get modified as it is not specified to be global inside your function.
Here is the corrected code:
class Store:
    def calc_cost(self, rate: float, qty: int) -> float:
        return rate * qty

def sum_stores(store1):
    global total
    total += store1.calc_cost(15, 30)

total = 0
ice_cream_shop = Store()
sum_stores(ice_cream_shop)
print(total)

In this case, the code would output a total of 450.

The code works by adding self, thank you! Just for clarification, is self necessary for every method defined in a class? Because from this code I would assume that self always takes a positional argument.

Yes, the self keyword is necessary for most functions inside a class, although helper functions and other minor use cases don't require it.

It is indeed possible, and you are on the right track.
In your code, you are trying to pass three arguments into sum_stores, namely ice_cream_shop, 1.5, and 30, but in you definition of the sum_stores function, you define it to take two arguments. You need the third argument in the definition.
Also, sum_stores takes an argument named total, which is not used in the function. So something should be corrected here also. I.e.,
def sum_stores(store1, rate, qty):
    cost = store1.calc_cost(rate, qty)
    return cost


They also need to define cost, possibly as sum_stores.cost, and Store.calc_cost needs to take its object and ignore it:  def calc_cost(_, rate: float, qty: int) -> float:

Fom your answer I realise that I accidentally posted incorrect code, mainly while I was experimenting. I have now copied from my original file, which gives me the same result.
class Store:
def calc_cost(rate: float, qty: int) -> float:
return rate * qty
def sum_stores(store1, total):
total += store1.calc_cost(15, 30)
total = 0
ice_cream_shop = Store()
sum_stores(ice_cream_shop, total)
(I have edited the main post where it would be clearer)

I see. I made a mistake in my answer, where I did not return the cost ( and there should not be a +=, which I have removed)

Even though your question was already answered, my approach to be straightforward would be something like this:
>>> class Store:
...     @staticmethod # This method can’t access or modify the class state, so 'self' is not required.
...     def calc_cost(rate: float, qty: int) -> float:
...         return rate * qty
...                                                                                                                            ...
>>> def sum_stores(store1: Store, total: int) -> float: # total parameter is never used.
...     return store1.calc_cost(15,30)
...
>>> total = 0
>>> ice_cream_shop = Store()
>>> total += sum_stores(ice_cream_shop, total)
>>> total
450
>>> total += sum_stores(ice_cream_shop, total)
>>> total
900

However my recommendation at the moment to use classes would be different, you need to analyze that any state is going to be handled, so classes are good way to do this, but, this case may be simpler, we don't need a class to calculate the cost, just the alone function works pretty well and it's more readable.
>>> def calc_cost(rate: float, qty: int) -> float:
...     return rate * qty
...
>>> total = 0
>>> cost = calc_cost(15.0, 30)
>>> total += cost
>>> total
450.0

I highly recommend watch this video to avoid bad practises in OOP.
